# AngularJS directive with change parameter lags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;      
  vm.unit = '';
  vm.unitForm = "unitForm";
  vm.unitInput = "unitInput";      
  vm.amount = '';
  vm.amountForm = "amountForm";
  vm.amountInput = "amountInput";      
  vm.errorText = "Error";
  vm.pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$");    
  vm.calculate = calculate;
  function calculate(first, second){
    var firstFloat = parseFloat(first.replace(",","."));
    var secondFloat = parseFloat(second.replace(",","."));
    var total = (firstFloat * secondFloat).toFixed(2);
    console.log('calculating', firstFloat, secondFloat, total)
    return total.toString().replace(".",",");
  }
});

app.directive('textInput', function textInput() {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'text-input.html',
     scope: {
       myClass: "@",
       value: '=?value',
       formName: '=',
       inputName: '=',
       pattern: '=',
       errorText: '=',
       change: "&"
     }
  };
});
```

text-input.html

```
<form name="formName">
    <input type="text"
           name="inputName"
           ng-model="value"
           ng-class="myClass"
           ng-pattern="pattern"
           ng-trim="false"
           ng-change="change()"
            />

    <div data-ng-show="formName.inputName.$error.pattern">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{errorText}}
    </div>
</form>
```

index.html

```
<text-input my-class="input"
                form-name="vm.unitForm" 
                input-name="vm.unitInput" 
                pattern="vm.pattern"
                error-text="vm.errorText"
                value="vm.unit"
                change="vm.total = vm.calculate(vm.amount, vm.unit)"
    ></text-input>

    <br>

    <text-input my-class="input"
                form-name="vm.amountForm" 
                input-name="vm.amountInput" 
                pattern="vm.pattern"
                error-text="vm.errorText"
                value="vm.amount"
                change="vm.total = vm.calculate(vm.amount, vm.unit)"
    ></text-input>

    vm.unit: {{vm.unit}}
    <br>
    vm.amount: {{vm.amount}}
    <br><br>

    Just jusing *:{{vm.unit*vm.amount}}
    <br>
    Change:
    {{vm.total}}
```

Link to plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DOc0v7o7arS6PhYOHaK0?p=preview

As can be seen, I have a directive that binds a variable to a function.
For some reason I can't figure out, the whole thing lags.

To see what's wrong do this: Enter a value in the top box, i.e 2. Enter a value in the second box, i.e 3.
The models lag in input. To see a change from the function, you need to enter another value. But the function now uses the values before your last input!

So, I am thoroughly confused here. What's going on and why won't this work?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this, I'm not getting any lag and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: This happens because when on-change is triggered, you get the old value (the new one hasn't registered yet). You can either use `$scope.$watch()` or a `$timeout`.

Comment: remember smth like this. Adding some dots solves this problem:http://plnkr.co/edit/pMgWWddmnk1RMDR0TkB8?p=preview

Comment: @OmriAharon Why has it not been registered yet though? Both variables are updated in the controller, but why can't the directive see them?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Interesting. Could you explain why it's needed to use `.value` on the variables and not just the variable directly? Also, it does not seem to work when you enter the value for the first time. Just typing "2" in the first box and "3" in the second box results in nothing. You have to type something like "2" and "33" for it to update correctly.